# How to set theme of XWPFTable in Apache POI?

Tags: java, apache-poi, document, cpu-word

I have the following table:

[image]

I want to give it a black theme:

[image]

My code is something like:

```
table = ForensicExpertWitnessReport_doc.insertNewTbl(cursor);

// Create first row of table // File Name
XWPFTableRow tableRowOne = table.getRow(0);
tableRowOne.getCell(0).setText("File Name");
tableRowOne.addNewTableCell();
 if (filename != null) {
    tableRowOne.getCell(1).setText(filename);
}
```

How do I do this? Is it possible?

**Update:** For example, in Microsoft Word it is:

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Not exactly clear what is meant here. Do you want applying a [table style](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/apply-table-styles-0f19e350-f9a1-4a9f-afdb-46ee2bb8460c)? But there is not exactly this style in the defaults. The closest would be "Grid Table 5 Dark". Or do you want formatting the table cells individually? If so then try the methods of [XWPFTableCell](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTableCell.html) (`XWPFTableCell.setColor`) and [XWPFRun](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html) (`XWPFRun.setColor`).

Comment: I have updated my original post - it's the shading/theme/background colour behind the text on the table that I'm looking for. If it isn't possible, then I will have to do something different, like Grid Table 5 Dark

Comment: Have you tried [XWPFTableCell.setColor](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTableCell.html#setColor-java.lang.String-)? For example `tableRowOne.getCell(0).setText("File Name"); tableRowOne.getCell(0).setColor("000000");`? If you have, what is the problem you have using this? And if you have a problem using this, where is `ForensicExpertWitnessReport_doc` coming from? Is it opened from a template `*.docx` file or is it created from scratch?

Comment: That acutally just worked amazing and set it exactly as in the picture. Did that for each row. Worked for each table that it is creating. Thank you very much!